# Does Azure DevOps GIT repo storage count as "Artifacts" for billing purposes?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Does storage of source in Azure Git repo count as "artifact storage" for purposes of billing?

It seems like it should be obvious but the documentation sometimes makes it sound like only the stuff that you produce in your build (or universal artifacts you specifically upload) count that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Git repositories do not count toward Artifact storage. Artifact storage includes packages and symbols.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  But if that's the case, what's to stop me from loading up 16 GB if test files, and other input into a big old Azure GIT repo instead of as a Universal Artifact?  I would then get all that storage for free, yes?

Comment: I only ask because nowhere can I find reference to Microsoft charging me for Git storage separately in any way.  So I see no barrier to just creating repos to store my input universal artifacts/blobs

Comment: @Joe Because Git repos are completely unsuitable for managing large files and you would very quickly realize that you made a huge mistake.

Comment: That makes sense but in this case, these files never change.  They're just static data.   All I have to be able to do is pull them for the build.  I never need to check one out and update it.  The files in question live in an external SVN server right now which we've long used for this purpose.  Since Azure won't let me pull from SVN and GIT in a single YAML build, I've so far been manually creating universal artifacts out of them.  But being able to just pull them in the build would be a lot easier

Comment: Actually I think I'll pose that as its own question so as to avoid discussion in comments